# 1 word title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to limit the title into 1 word only 
I tried using this code but it doesn't return anything..

```
<?php   
   $title = get_the_title();
   $names = explode(' ', $title);
   echo $names[0];
?>
```

This is where I'm trying to implement the code If I change the **`get_the_title()`** into **`$names[0]`** but it doesn't return anything.

```
$postheader .= '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in the content of $title? The explode/split should work in that fashion, so there are a couple of things you can do to try to debug:

First, check the content of $title. You can do this as simply as outputting is and viewing source: make sure it has actual spaces, and not non-breaking spacing, or that the field does not start with a space.

Second, make sure your first code block is actually getting executed by echo'ing something you can check for in source, or any other method to ensure it is running. Good luck!